# Windows 10 Keeps Bluescreening with Clock Watchdog Error

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I also tried to run sfc /scannow, but it couldn't repair some files, even in safe mode. 
Info from reliability monitor:

```
    Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
    Code:   101
    Parameter 1:    18
    Parameter 2:    0
    Parameter 3:    ffffd00024c50180
    Parameter 4:    2
    OS version: 10_0_10586
    Service Pack:   0_0
    Product:    256_1
    OS Version: 10.0.10586.2.0.0.256.48
    Locale ID:  1033
```

And

```
    Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
    Code:   101
    Parameter 1:    18
    Parameter 2:    0
    Parameter 3:    ffffd001db850180
    Parameter 4:    2
    OS version: 10_0_10586
    Service Pack:   0_0
    Product:    256_1
    OS Version: 10.0.10586.2.0.0.256.48
    Locale ID:  1033
```

If there are any files I could upload for more information, please tell me.

Comment: You are not running the current build of Windows 10.  Can you resolve that problem?  You need to run windbg to determine the cause of the BSOD.

Comment: Version 10.0.10586.2 is out of date; the current version is 10.0.10586.494 (as of the July 2016 updates).

Comment: It says I'm up to date. Would there be any reason why it's not giving me some updates?

Comment: @Hafo - You are over **9 months** out of date.  You are not even running the original 10586 build, which excluding people who updated manually, ended up being 10586.3 when Version 1511 was actually released.

Comment: Okay, but I installed an update yesterday. I have no idea why it's not updating. Windows Update Diagnostic said nothing also.

Comment: I suggest you download the current Windows 10 .ISO and do an in-place upgrade.  If your system cannot or will not update that is the best way to solve the problem.  It also might solve, what I assume is corrupt system files, since you indicate SFC was not able to perform the repair on (what I assume) are corrupt files.

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\windows\minidump, so that we can debug them

Comment: I can't find any minidump files, and I just attempted to do an in-place upgrade. It took forever to download and it STAYED AT THE SAME VERSION. I'm going to bed, maybe I'll do a clean install tomorrow and pray for a miracle.

Comment: have you disable the pagefile? Windows needs it to generate dumps. also notify my with @ myusername so that I can see that you replied

Comment: @magicandre1981
Alright, problem is still occurring after clean install. Minidump is here:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/qcwbbybtq8yudl4/072016-12359-01.dmp

Comment: this looks like a HW issue. Have you done OverClocking to the 2500k in the past?

Comment: @magicandre1981 While I  have overclocked my GPU, I don't believe I've ever overclocked my CPU.

Comment: but the dmp shows 1 core is unresponsive. look if the BIOS allows you to disable some cores. do this until you find which core hags and run the PC without the core.

Comment: A new question with similar symptoms: https://superuser.com/questions/1310887/bsod-clock-watchdog-timeout-windows-10

Answer (score 1):

Oh, sorry for forgetting about this question. As it turns out, my CPU heatsink fan was dying, and as such the CPU was overheating quite a bit. I haven't had issues since replacing it.